# .net ListView eventValidation error after RegisterforEventValidation

Tags: asp.net, listview, eventvalidation

I have the following Listview defined

```
<asp:ListView 
        ID="reportData" 
        EnableSortingAndPagingCallback="True"
        AllowPaging="True"
        AllowSorting="True"
        PageSize="20" 
        OnLayoutCreated="LoadReport"
        onsorting="reportData_Cause_Sorting" 
        OnPagePropertiesChanging="reportData_PagePropertiesChanging"
        runat="server">
```

I also have a DataPager defined

```
<asp:DataPager ID="reportPager" PagedControlID="reportData" PageSize="20" runat="server" >
    <Fields>
        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
```

Then, since i Have enableEventValidation set to true, i also have the item registered

```
   Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(reportData.UniqueID)
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(reportPager.UniqueID)
        MyBase.Render(writer)
    End Sub
```

My Initial page load runs just fine, however when I click on a page navigation I am sent to the codebehind and get through the page_load before I receive the error

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

I just don't understand why I am continuing to receive the error after I have registered both items for event validation.  I never even make it into the RaiseCallbackEvent!

I am a total newbie to these controls and by no means a .net expert either.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  I was calling my function to load the report data and bind it to the ListView both in OnLoad and Render.  When I removed the extra call from OnLoad, I no longer received the message.  However, paging is still not working, but the problem has moved to a different spot in the code :)

Comment: I just want to note I found this post to be extremely helpful in getting everything working just right http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130439/asp-net-datapager-control-always-a-step-behind-with-paging

Answer (score 0):

try this simple example.

url passes the values ​​of the paging

```
protected void DepartmentsListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    MessageLabel.Text = "The key value is " +
      CountriesListView.SelectedValue.ToString() + ".";
}
```

```
<asp:ListView ID="CountriesListView" DataSourceID="ContactsDataSource" runat="server"
    DataKeyNames="FirstName" OnItemCommand="DepartmentsListView_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="4" width="500" runat="server" id="tblCountries">
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                <th id="Th0" runat="server">
                    ID
                </th>
                <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                    Code
                </th>
                <th id="Th2" runat="server">
                    Name
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SelectButton" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CountryCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmployeeID")%>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>


 <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="DataPager2" PageSize="3" PagedControlID="CountriesListView"
    QueryStringField="pageNumber">
    <Fields>
        <asp:NumericPagerField />
    </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
```

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ContactsDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conecec %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [EmployeeID], [FirstName], [LastName] FROM Employees">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to change `EventValidation` or use `RegisterForEventValidation` 
Put this code in `Page_Load` event

```
if (!IsPostBack)
  {
     BindData();
  }
```

And do not forget modify the `PagePropertiesChanged` Event of `ListViews` :

```
protected void lstProducts_PagePropertiesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindData();
    }
```