# ASP.NET Update Panel within ListView Control not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, updatepanel

Basically I have this situation

Page >
   Update Panel >
       User Control >
           List View  >
               User Control (Within item template) >
                   Update Panel

When I click on a button within the inner most update panel, I want the content of the update panel to update. This isn't happening. However, the click handler is being hit fine asynchronously. The update panel just doesn't want to update.

**Code** - I've created a simple test web app that replicates the problem, and shared it on my google drive: [UpdatePanelInListViewTest.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4skfAO1E7ZvWnZaLVE2eUpFRk0/edit?usp=sharing), but here's the markup:

Page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ajaxParent" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <uc1:ListUserControl ID="ListUserControl1" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

List User Control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ListUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UpdatePanelInListViewTest.ListUserControl" %>
<%@ Register src="MiniWidget.ascx" tagname="MiniWidget" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<asp:ListView ID="lstTest" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Item
        <uc1:MiniWidget ID="MiniWidget1" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Mini Widget User Control

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MiniWidget.ascx.cs" Inherits="UpdatePanelInListViewTest.MiniWidget" %>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ajaxWidget" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTest" runat="server" onclick="lnkTest_Click">Test</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've tried different permutations of this; i.e. having the button outside the panel and adding a trigger etc but I just cannot get it to update.

It appears that because the user control is within an item template of the parent list view it causes the update panel to not update for some reason...

Comment: Is UpdateMode="Conditional" on your top-level UpdatePanel ? Can you try changing it to "Always" ?

Comment: I've tried both. No success

Comment: Btw I don't want the parent to update, so it should be set to conditional.

Comment: Can you post the markup for your page and for the parent usercontrol, so I can try this myself and see what's happening ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4skfAO1E7ZvWnZaLVE2eUpFRk0/edit?usp=sharing

Does this link work? I've created a test project with the problem replicated. When you click the link within the items it should update a label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to do with when you call the *databind* method within *ListUserControl*.

Moving `lstTest.DataBind();` so that it executes within the `Page_Load` rather than the `Page_PreRender` fixes the issue for your *simple test web app*.

Comment: Yep. Nice one. I put it in the pre render because of issues with using the data pager with the list view: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234289/listview-with-datapager-not-working) but it really doesn't make sense to do the databind in the pre render.

Answer (score 0):

have u tried:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ajaxPanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTest" />
 </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" onclick="btnTest_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Have U ScriptManager on .aspx page?

Comment: Yes. Download the test app

Comment: [check this](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=FFA1892AB8C64748%21127) I just added 2 labels -> one in update panell and one in normal aspx content. When u Click button this one in Updatepannel will update w/o autopostback